# Linux/Ubuntu: How to make archive when there are too many files (6GB = 3 000 files)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, archiving, tar

So, how to make a few archive parts or how to make archive for some part of files (0-100 items, than 1000-200 items etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't. Tarpipe it.

```
ssh user@host tar cjf - files/to/archive > backup.tar.bz2
```

This will build the tarball on the remote side and send the results to your system, where it gets put into a file called "backup.tar.bz2".

Comment: Got error then: Filesize limit exceeded: 25

Comment: Drop the `j` and the `.bz2` then, so that it doesn't produce *any* files on the remote system.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `split` if you have to.  Tar it to one archive and then use this command.

Comment: The main problem is that I haven't any roots for edit privilages on my hosting. And when I make an archive I get an error: "Filesize limit exceeded: 25"

Comment: @Anthony That's a problem.  You would have to make a lot of archives and give them out.  This wouldn't be nice.  And by the way, if it's a backup of all your stuff, can't you ask the admin?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is almost impossible. If anybody doesn't help me, then will try to ask the admin...